# An alternate version of "The Chronicles of Riddick" (2014) where William J. Johns appears?

Tags: alternate-version, riddick

Yesterday I watched [The Chronicles of Riddick (2004)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296572/). The movie that I watched starts with an opening scene showing one of Necromongers invasion and Elemental seer's voice explaining who these creatures are and what they do.

While reading on Riddick's franchise in general in Wikipedia, I stepped into "[Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick_%28franchise%29?wprov=sfla1#Characters)" section which says about William J. Johns, played by Cole Hauser (emphasis mine):

> He eventually catches Riddick on the planet Aquila Major (**featured in the opening scene of Chronicles of Riddick**) by killing two children and threatening to kill two more unless Riddick surrenders.

Is there any longer (director's cut etc.) version of the movie that has above cited scenes that were certainly deleted from the version of the movie that I watched?

For the record: there is neither any appearance nor even any mention about William J. Johns in the version of "The Chronicles of Riddick" (2004) that I watched (or maybe I am blind).

Comment: I would wait for a couple of days or so before accepting any answer. This can encourage others to answer on their own, and you might get different opinions or things that were missed

Answer (score 1):

## Aquila Major (the planet) is featured in the movie's intro, not the actual capture scene

Aquila Major is shown here:

The story about Johns is taken from different media, including [diaries](https://riddick.fandom.com/wiki/Johns,_William_J._-_Pursuit_Log) found in the videogames.

> "I'm leaving the Conga System with Riddick in tow. I would'a never never guessed he had such a soft spot in his little heart. (Mockingly) Children in peril (laughs). He's fucking stupid like that. Should'a known that'd slow him down too much. I hope that this slam can hold him, and I hope those boys at Tangiers saved their paychecks."

That scene has never feature in any movie.